# Are there faster dead men than the Flash?

Tags: dc, the-flash

The Flash's title is "The Fastest Man Alive."

[image: A front cover to a "The Flash" comic book showing the Flash running to the right hand side with the tagline "The Fastest Man Alive"]

The modifier "Alive" implies that there was at least one faster man, but he is no longer alive.

In the main comic continuities, are there men faster than the Flash who died some time in the past?

Comment: It implies no such thing

Comment: @WayneInYak Care to elaborate?

Comment: @RogueJedi You are inferring something which is not necessarily implied. To assume that 'fastest man *alive*' means there's a dead person that was faster is like affirming the consequent, a classical fallacy in logic.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't imply that dead men are faster, and it also doesn't imply that any women are faster.

Comment: It would be interesting if there are men who are currently dead and currently faster than the fastest man alive.  (I doubt it, as I'm led to understand there are two kinds of people, the quick and the dead.)

Comment: Usain Bolt is called the 'fastest man alive' and sometimes 'the fastest man in the world' but he is technically 'the fastest person ever timed' or 'the fastest person on record'

Answer (score 5):

> "Fastest man alive" allows for the possibility that there used to be a faster man, but it doesn't imply that there ever **was** a faster person. - [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlashTV/comments/49zr0p/fastest_man_alive_phrase_meaning/?) (emphasis added)

The Fastest Man Alive appears to be an alternate name/title for The Flash, and is not meant to imply definitive speed prowess(ɤ) of those either living or dead. His other two titles are The Scarlet Speedster and The Sultan of Swoosh (possibly only from The Joker).

**This can be implied by the titling [The Flash: The Fastest Man Alive](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Flash:_The_Fastest_Man_Alive_Vol_1).**

> In books and other works, a subtitle is an explanatory or alternate title. [Wikipedia - Subtitling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_(titling)) ɫ

In Earth 2 and other places, it is referenced as a title or distinction.

> After the events of Crisis on Infinite Earths where Barry Allen was killed, Wally took over as the Fastest Man Alive. - [Wikipedia: The Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(comics)#Wally_West)

ɤ Guinness has yet to collaborate The Flash's claim.

ɫ The title *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* seems to imply that Captain America (the person) is alternatively called The Winter Soldier, but it doesn't (spoiler).